# FFMPEG- AWS Lambda Function Issue

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have created a aws lamda function  with node js fluent-ffmpeg
so in this use ffmpeg and ffprob for use create a video , scaling and converting video using serverless application. where aws lambda deployment package created more than 50 mb because i am using with the help of ffmpeg and ffprob exe (binary library). so i can not upload a deployment zip file. can do with any solution,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use new AWS Lambda called Layers. It allows you to include some custom artifacts, especially large binaries. Your exact case was described here: https://serverless.com/blog/publish-aws-lambda-layers-serverless-framework/