# NodeJS: Extract frames from MP4 video

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, video-capture

Does anyone know of a NodeJS library that would let me extract frames from an MP4 video stream? I know I can do it with ffmpeg, but I need this to run in an AWS Lambda, so I don't (easily) have that at my disposal. And since it's a Lambda, I would like something pretty lightweight and not filesystem dependent.

I looked at the [node-video-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-video-lib) package which I was able to use to open a stream from S3 and read metadata of a video, but I don't see an obvious way to extract a frame image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a snapshot still of a video in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802484/how-do-i-get-a-snapshot-still-of-a-video-in-nodejs)

Comment: Running ffmpeg on lambda has been documented a few times. It's not that easy, but doing it node-native would be incredibly complex, really reinventing the wheel

Comment: Lambda-specific ffmpeg/node SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539103/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-function-issue

Comment: The static binary's for ffmpeg from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ have worked well for me.

Comment: Ok, kinda what I thought. Just wanted to be sure before I went down the ffmpeg/lambda layers route.